# Rails 4: OR in where clause not working with querying nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to query any Company in my database where the field visible is either NULL or true. Here is what I found on a Stackoverflow post:

```
@companies = Company.where('visible=? OR visible=?', nil, true).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Somehow though, this does not seem to work for querying nil. When I use this code, displaying all companies where visible is nil works very well though.

```
@companies = Company.where('visible' => nil).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

I would very much appreciate any ideas here.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

This still displays only companies where visible is nil:

```
@companies = Company.where('visible is ? OR visible=?', nil, true).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because 
`Company.where('visible=?', nil)` makes query:

> Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE
>   (visible = NULL)

In SQL, to compare with *NULL*, `=` doesn't work. It requires `IS` instead.

`Company.where('visible is ?', nil)` should do the trick for you. Add or statement along with it.

> Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE
>   (visible is NULL)

OR, the perfect way:

```
Company.where(:visible => [true, nil])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just tried this out and updated my question. Even though I am now using "is" for my nil query, I only see companies where visible is nil.

Comment: `visible` is boolean field, right? Can you check your SQL for values and double-check if it shows 0 for false, 1 for true and null for absence? `true` in query translates to `1` for boolean field.

Comment: Visible is indeed a boolean field. I have one test company with true and all the others currently have NULL in the database.

Comment: Can you verify if this queries gives you the right rows in your sql : `SELECT companies.* FROM companies WHERE (visible is NULL or visible is 1)`. If yes, then there is no reason why ActiveRecord shouldn't :). If not, please check the data.

Comment: WHERE (visible is NULL or visible is true) - this gives me the correct rows

Comment: But even Company.where(:visible => [true, nil]) does only display all companies with nil in the visible field.

Comment: Actually, the NULL is not a value, but a flag that shows that here is no value. Because you can't compare value with no value you need to check if the attribute of tuple has attribute or no.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have no NOT NULL constraint in your DB.

You can also use conditional expressions(`CASE`) or function `COALESCE`.

Comment: How would I go about adding this?

Comment: For new tables and column you need to add ```null: false``` option. For already existing tables/columns you need to make ```ALTER TABLE``` or to use AR's ```change_table``` method.

Here is stupid simple example:


```
create_table :my_table do |t|
  t.column :title, :string, null: false
end
```